# How to conditionally set a data-attribute in vue3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I'm trying, depending on if my loops index is 0 or not to set a data-attribute on a h2-tag. What i want is that it should render as `data-title="main"` if the index is 0. How would i do that? Now its not rendering the data-attribute at all.

Code:

(projects is an already parsed json, without, errors)

```
  <figure v-for="(project, index) in projects" :key="project.id">
    <figcaption>
      <span>
        {{ project.subtitle }}
      </span>
      <h2 :data-title="{'main': index == 0}">
        {{ project.title }}
      </h2>
    </figcaption>
  </figure>
```

Comment: `:data-title="index == 0 ? 'main' : undefined"` I guess

Comment: @Dimava Would you mind posting your comment as an answer, so the OP can accept it? This benefits both of you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike style attribute that wants a object

```js
<div :style="{ display: index == 0 ? "block" : undefined }" />
```

most of the other attributes have other value types
In your case, it's `string`

```js
<div :data-title="index == 0 ? 'main' : 'otherwise'" />
```

Pass `undefined` or `null` to make Vue remove the attribute completely.

```js
<div :data-title="index == 0 ? 'main' : undefined " />
```